# Why the User has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-queryset

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ali/MAKEEN/makeen-tasks/ali/tasks/user/venv/user/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ali/MAKEEN/makeen-tasks/ali/tasks/user/venv/user/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ali/MAKEEN/makeen-tasks/ali/tasks/user/venv/user/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 55, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ali/MAKEEN/makeen-tasks/ali/tasks/user/venv/user/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ali/MAKEEN/makeen-tasks/ali/tasks/user/venv/user/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/ali/MAKEEN/makeen-tasks/ali/tasks/user/venv/user/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/ali/MAKEEN/makeen-tasks/ali/tasks/user/venv/user/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/ali/MAKEEN/makeen-tasks/ali/tasks/user/venv/user/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ali/MAKEEN/makeen-tasks/ali/tasks/user/api/views.py", line 75, in post
    user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'objects'
[04/Mar/2023 11:12:44] "POST /password-reset/ HTTP/1.1" 500 101524
```

views.py

```
class PasswordReset(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.EmailSerializer

    def post(self, request):

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        email = serializer.data["email"]
        user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
        if user:
            encoded_pk = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
            token = PasswordResetTokenGenerator().make_token(user)


            reset_url = reverse("reset-password", kwargs={"encoded_pk": encoded_pk, "token": token})

            rest_url = f"localhost:8000{reset_url}"

            return Response(
                {
                    "message":
                        f"Your password reset link: {rest_url}"
                },
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
            )
        else:
            Response(
                {
                    "message": "User doesn't exists"
                },
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )
```

serializers.py

```
class EmailSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        field = ("email",)
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback of error? Also you are using custom user model or built in `User` model?

Comment: @SunderamDubey There is no any model, I used
`
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
`

Comment: Ok, so share the full error traceback.

Comment: @SunderamDubey here it is, i hope you can help me

Comment: Maybe you need to add `'rest_framework.authtoken'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`  in `settings.py` and then run migration commands.

Comment: @SunderamDubey Oh no I found ,  I had another class called User in my views and i couldn't manipulate on the User `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` I set it as BaseUser and the problem solved

Comment: @SunderamDubey Your request to add the whole error opened my eyes, Thank you